# Exclude some headings from numbering

Tags: org-mode

I would like to exclude some headings from numbering in `org-num-mode`.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: @NickD Thanks. Please post this as an answer and I will accept it. Just one small question. Is there a way to set or-num-skip-tags on a per-file basis?

Comment: Done - added a note about file local variables and links to the relevant docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the commentary in the [file](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/master/lisp/org-num.el#L23): "You can select what is numbered according to level, tags, `COMMENT` keyword, or `UNNUMBERED` property. You can also skip footnotes sections. See `org-num-max-level`, `org-num-skip-tags`, `org-num-skip-commented`, `org-num-skip-unnumbered`, and `org-num-skip-footnotes` for details."

For setting `org-num-skip-tags` (or most other variables) per file, one can always use [file local variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables). For example:

```
* foo
  foo

  
* bar                                     :unnumbered:
  bar


  
* baz
  baz
  
* Local variables                         :unnumbered:

# Local Variables:
# org-num-skip-tags: ("unnumbered")
# End:
```

It's a very general customization mechanism.